# laravel how to pass the paramters to the query scope?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

look at code first:

```
$bookname = 'www';
User::with(array('roles' => function($query) {
    $query->where('bookname' => $bookname);
}))->find(1);
```

but it lead an error"undefined variable $bookname"..how to fix this?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong syntax.

```
$bookname = 'www';
User::with(array('roles' => function($query) use ($bookname) {
    $query->where('bookname', '=', $bookname);
}))->find(1);
```

To use the `$bookname` inside of the anonymous function you need to pass it using `use` statement. In addition `where()` function inside your anonymous function takes 3 parameters:
**column name, comparing operator, search value.**

Comment: so with above code: how can I update the record that I find..for example:  $ret = User::with(array('roles' => function($query) use ($bookname) {
    $query->where('bookname', '=', $bookname);
}))->find(1);  $ret->bookname = 'something others';

Comment: If you simply need to update a single record why not just use `$user = User::where('bookname', '=', $bookname)->get();` `$user->bookname...;`

Comment: Because I divide the "logic " into "Respository"s ,I don't want my A Respository has a dependency with Respository B